How to fix recurring boot issues for ubuntu 22.04 VM on windows 10?
On windows 10 I have a ubuntu 22.04 VM which sometimes does not start, i.e. I get an error like this:

I then usually turn off the machine and restart it and I enter "emergency mode":

Unfortunately I cannot copy-paste the output of journalctl -xb and typing the thousands of lines is a bit over the top. However, one error I see is
vmwgfx seems to be running on an unsupported hypervisor

but no idea if this is related. So, I then reboot the VM again and enter one of the RAM-test modes, start testing RAM, then stop it and reboot.
Then the machine reboots just normally. No issues. All is fine. No change whatsoever.
Is there any way to avoid the above cumbersome procedure and to make sure the VM always boots? Or maybe there is a way to shorten the above mentioned procedure?
I followed the instructions given in the answer of enter link description here but the issue still seems to be there. Like currently I see the loading screen, but for minutes, then I stop the VM, start again. See the loading screen for minutes, then stop and start the VM. Then I start some memcheck (when that optional finally pops up) let the memcheck run for some seconds, then stop it, let the VM restart and finally, after 3 or 5 th trial, ubuntu starts normally ! And then I have forgotten what I actually wanted to do ;-)

I followed the instructions in that link, but the problem seems to remain

Ok retracted, so everything is now back to normal.
